# How do I extract just the name (or version number) from my Ubuntu release on the command line?

Tags: ubuntu, bash

I only want one of the following values:

- 11.10
- oneiric

I've tried checking out `lsb_release -r` and `uname -a`, but the output is still verbose without using `grep`. This is the closest I've gotten to:

- distribution name: 
  `grep -oP 'CODENAME=(.+)' -m 1 /etc/lsb-release | awk -F= '{ print $NF }'`
- version number: 
  `grep -oP '\d+\.\d+' -m 1 /etc/lsb-release`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The easiest way is is to use `-s` or `--short`:

```
lsb_release -si 
#  Ubuntu

lsb_release -sr
#  11.04

lsb_release -sir
#  Ubuntu
#  11.04
```

Answer (score 9):

For release:

```
$ lsb_release --release
Release:    11.04
```

For codename:

```
$ lsb_release --codename
Codename:   natty
```

To get just `11.04` or `natty` you can use `cut`. For example:

```
$ lsb_release --release | cut -f2
11.04
```

For everything:

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 11.04
Release:    11.04
Codename:   natty
```